# Construct a regular expression for a given language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I'm currently working on some exercises to get used to create regular expressions from given languages and i'm stuck with a fairly simple exercise. So could you please tell me how to construct it step by step (if possible) from this given language. I would really appreciate your help.

L={w∈{a,b,c}∗:w contains an odd number of one or more of a,b or c}

Comment: I don't think this can be done. In some sense, you're trying to count the total occurrences of a letter in an arbitrarily long string with other letters.

Answer (score 1):

For starters: an even number of $a$'s: $((b+c)^*a(b+c)^*a(b+c)^*)^*$.